Weird Property of Irrational Numbers and their "Conjugate"
Let us have a irrational number $a$. Let $a'$ be $\frac{1}{a'} + \frac{1}{a} = 1$. If we let $A$ and $B$ be sets such that $A =$ {$\lfloor a \rfloor, \lfloor 2a \rfloor, \lfloor 3a \rfloor, \lfloor 4a \rfloor ...$} and {$\lfloor a' \rfloor, \lfloor 2a' \rfloor, \lfloor 3a' \rfloor, \lfloor 4a' \rfloor ...$}. After an analysis, I noted that $A$ and $B$ have no similar terms for the initial irrational $\phi$, $e$, and $\pi$. Could someone help me prove why? Thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What does it mean for two sets not to have similar terms?

This follows from properties of Beatty sequences; see for example this Wikipedia page.

So the floors of each term multiplied are never the same, ie.
f(x) = ax
g(y) = by
f(x) is never equal to g(y)

This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!
